# CC YouTube Ad Revenue

Tags: copyright, creative-commons

With Creative Commons, imagine that I have a Blender (3D animation) file where in combination with the Blender program, people can freely create their own modification of my animation located inside the Blender file and export a video of the animation using the Blender Program onto their computer.

I plan to add a Creative Commons license to this but I'm having trouble to choose which one. My aim is for people to use the exported video and post it on youtube safely, allowing them to use ad revenue. However, I do not want them to use the content by selling my blender file, even if they modified it (because it's free in the first place). I also do not want to sell the videos exported from that blender file (because it's a free product of a free software and a free file). What should I do?

Comment: So you only care about the distribution of videos created with the helpf of your Blender file, not about the distribution of the Blender file (possibly changed by users)? -- I don’t know Blende -- could you describe what such a Blender file contains? Would the created videos contain your own resources (e.g. textures), or is it just a helper that makes creating animations easier which could also be created without your file?

Comment: I care about both. A blender file contains textures for the 3D objects, as well as the objects themselves, their shapes, positions, movement and etc. They are not a helper tool to make animating easier. People just download the blender file, open it in blender, change the text in the file, convert it into a video (rendering it) and use it as their youtube Intro or outro. It's basically an intro template.

Comment: @Bradman175 Whatever you do, don't license it under CC on YouTube, as you can only choose between CC BY and the standard youtube license. (Speaking of which, this would make a great question on [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com) :)

Comment: @Zizouz212 I'm not. It's the copyright configuration of the blender file I'm worried about. I took care of the promotion video.